# Voice transmission path in a Smart Phone

Tags: android, embedded-linux, smartphone, firefox-os, firefox-developer-tools

I would like to understand the processing of the voice on a SmartPhone (say for example running Android/ Firefox OS). Voice received on the mic goes through some driver in the OS and is fed as an input to the transmission unit (Radio interface) which then transmits the signal?

I would like look at some code examples. I've been trying to find this in the Firefox os code.

```
        TelephonyCall::ChangeStateInternal
    {
        <SNIP>
        nsRefPtr<CallEvent> event = CallEvent::Create(this);
        NS_ASSERTION(event, "This should never fail!");

        if (NS_FAILED(event->Dispatch(ToIDOMEventTarget(),
                                      NS_LITERAL_STRING("statechange")))) {
          NS_WARNING("Failed to dispatch statechange event!");
        }

    }
```

This looks to be the initial steps in the RX/Tx of phone calls. I could not find any reference to the code which gets the voice data from the microphone. Am I looking at the wrong part of the code.

I would like to understand how it is done in the code (Any open source 'mobile' OS is fine). Any pointers to the code / documentation is appreciated.

Thanks,
Bhargava.

Comment: *"Voice received on the mic goes through some driver in the OS"*  -- Drivers do not process signals.  Drivers provide a control interface to a device.  The "voice" is an acoustic signal that the microphone converts to an (analog) electrical signal. That analog signal is converted to digital, and then compressed and encoded by a (HW?) codec before the processor can handle this "voice" data.